# which category does "split" fall into?

Tags: functional-programming

I am curious which category  does ＂split＂ operation fall into ?
Map is one to one mapping between a collection to another collection, while reduce is a collection into a lower dimension, or a scalar. Then which category does "split" fall into, a collection or a scalar transform into a collection of a collection with a bigger size. Notation wise a->[b], is there a category in FP for this ? Thanks

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but can you elaborate on how this is a C++ question?

Comment: You'd need to define further what you mean by `split`, but I'm pretty sure it's a `fold`.

Comment: the closest thing i found is [unfold](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#unfold) , ramdajs docs define unfold as `(a → [b]) → * → [b]` , and split can be implemented using it.